# Big label in the button makes FlowPane grow

Tags: button, layout, javafx, text, flowpane

I made `Button` with max width of 300 and input a long text in it. `Button` got max size, but `FlowPane`, which also has max size of 300, grew in width. How comes that `Button` text is affecting `FlowPane` width? How to prevent it from happening?
Screenshot:

[image]

*`FlowPane` is marked with yellow border.*

`Button` settings:

[image]

`FlowPane` settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the `FlowPane` inside an `AnchorPane`. Set the `AnchorPane` sizes to the `FlowPane` sizes. At the very least, set the left and right `AnchorPane` constraints of the `FlowPane` to 0.

[image]

> Is `FlowPane` really the Node you want here?

Comment: I guess, as long as I have one button there, I can use `AnchorPane` for that. But in cases if I would need it for several elements? Why it's being stretched by text inside of my button even though it has it's max width? Is it a bug?

Comment: I have no Idea why it is displaying this behavior or if it's a bug.  Reading [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/FlowPane.html) may help.